# Fetching Pointers In Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I have a class in Parse called "WorkoutExercise" with pointers to other objects and i am trying to retrieve the workout exercises with the pointed objects as part of the objects too.

But when i execute the following code, none of the pointed objects show up in the workoutexercise object.

I tried includeKey("Exercise"), but that does not seem to work. Any clues?

Code:

```
//  Return pfobjects casted as exercises for a given workout
func getExercisesForWorkout(workout:Workout!, completion: ([WorkoutExercise]!, NSError!) -> Void ){
    var query = PFQuery(className:"WorkoutExercise")
    query.orderByAscending ("sequence")
    query.whereKey("Workout", equalTo: workout)
    query.includeKey("Exercise")
    query.includeKey("Workout")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            completion(objects as? [WorkoutExercise], error)
    }
}
```

In Parse:

[image]

Result:

```
[<WorkoutExercise: 0x7feef1c57700, objectId: Q9KeD4WiuH, localId: (null)> {
    Workout = "<Workout: 0x7feef1e89150, objectId: 1PQCrl3f8L>";
    reps = 10;
    sequence = 1;
    weight = 20;
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i know the mistake.

You are not supposed to name your pointers with the uppercase.

Changed the pointers to lower case and all is well.